# AJAX to call java method

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

There are many similar questions but I am not clear about one thing as mentioned below-

I have ajax call

```
var url = '/test/testjsp.do?param1=' + xyz;    
$.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    dataType:'html',
                    url:url,
                    success:function (data) {
                        alert("Success");
                    }
                });
```

which is calling an JSP page 
and in that file, I am calling method from SM class

```
<%@ page import="com.testAjax.SM" %>

<%

    if (null != request.getParameter("
        SM.randomMethod(request.getParameter("param1"));
    }
%>
```

So my question is ,

***I there any alternative method where I don't have to create extra Jsp file and call java method directly from Ajax call***

Please help and Advise

Answer (score 0):

As javascript is a client side script, it cannot invoke java methods directly which resides on the server.

To do that you have to create a web service or jsp like you did.

But I have seen `vaadin` gives option to call java code from javascript without writing a service or jsp. I dont know how it will help you.

https://vaadin.com/tutorials/calling-java-from-javascript

There are some concept like java adaptors and javavm to combine javascript and java try them to find it suits your need.